# How do I toggle headset/headphone mode manually?

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack, samsung-galaxy-spica

It seems that the hardware erroneously regard the headset as attached at all times (to the 3.5" jack). This makes me unable to make calls without headset or speaker mode.

Comment: I experienced the same issue, but "Fix Speaker" app resolved it with just one click. Now, sound comes from the speaker.
Download the app from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.multaitechnology.fix_speaker_disable_earphone_headphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I can solve the problem by jacking in the headphone, turning off the phone, turning on the phone again, and jacking out/in the headphone a few times **slowly**.

And yes, it is a hardware problem solved by a hardware solution.

Comment: restarting the phone? it sounds more like a software/hardware combo.. ;)

Answer (score 9):

This is a hardware problem, but there is an app called [toggleheadset2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dwalkes.android.toggleheadset2) that has a widget that allows you to override the hardware switch, toggling headset output off/on.

Comment: Toggleheadset2 does indeed control the headset mode the way you said. (Thanks for sharing the link!!!!) However, on my phone it does not affect the status bar headset icon!

Comment: 404 link ; @ak1

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a hardware issue to me. You should return the phone to wherever you bought it.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your headphones, power down the phone, power on the phone then remove the headphones.  This worked on my GS3. on my GS3 the headphone icon was never on, but the phone was stuck in headset mode. Could not hear any calls, could not hear any music, UNLESS the headphones were plugged in.  The speaker and Bluetooth icons were disabled so I could not switch to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem with my Samsung Galaxy Note III. It always thinks that headphones are plugged in. I even replaced the headphone jack and cleaned the contacts but the problem persisted. I found [HF Button Widget (<=KitKat)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chislonchow.toggleheadp). As the name suggests it supposedly only works on KitKat or below, and I'm on lollipop. But it actually did work for me.

So with this I get a widget which I use to toggle the headphones. I practically always have it at the off-setting, which makes the phone behave as it normally would with no headphones plugged in, e.g. I can use the native speaker toggle in calls to switch between earpiece and speaker. I very rarely use headphones which means the problem for me is completely solved in that sense.
When I do want to use headphones I have a one-click widget to use.
One minor annoyance is that the headphones icon always stay in the status bar.

Comment: I had the same problem where if I unplugged my earphones, the phone would act as though they were still plugged in. What I used to do is restart my phone after a couple of times unplugging and re-plugging the earphones. A few days ago, I started closing the apps that use the earphones, clearing `Recent items` in Android Q terms. Problem solved. No restart necessary.